# Communists and Christians

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. Singer Collins is performing leads for Prince (6)
5. Broken spine leads to aches (5)
10. Say, 33 across and Cuiabá's northern tip, described by excellent lyric poems (9)
11. Predecessor to NATO's uniform is brown next to green light (5)
12. Invalid character in Greek lines (4)
13. Jennifer Lopez briefly touring Orkney's westernmost island (4)
14. Indication of battalion's last soldiers retreating (4)
17. Return from Australian wilderness, heading to western part of Perth (3,4)
19. "50% off!" Judy goes inside to save money one snowy spring? (3,4)
20. Yankee backer is in Cuba, struggling with no tongue (7)
22. Islamic extremists removed from Christian church east of Staten Island (7)
23. Broadcast makes money describing vases (4)
24. Boy gets hold of university's head to get praise (4)
25. Discussion about Panama? (4)
29. A communist caught man packing (5)
31. Wearing flippin' fine suit, gentleman's opening entertainment venue (9)
32. One involved in drug traffic from the East managed company (5)
33. Old woman acquired dye for yellow-brown paper (6)

**Down**
2. Old communist allowed back to lodging (5)
3. Round sung for northerner (4)
4. Topmost of dials turned left in horse enclosure's security feature (7)
5. Former or present centre for preachers (7)
6. Crazy shock coming up (4)
7. Mentally stable pilot essentially obtains fighter uniform and beverage (3,6)
8. Boxer's male carer (dad) almost quit acting lead in Colorado (5,8)
9. Carelessly point out a numb peak (5,8)
15. Avocado production boycotted by Orange County city (5)
16. Slightly intoxicated? Last of whisky and saliva being thrown up (5)
18/30. Batman – no decayed fossil (5,3)
21. City at the heart of major land operations (7)
22. According to Spooner, attach backside to eucalyptus tree (4,3)
26. Harry and Albert not banned (5)
27. Heartless stranger illustrates German river (4)
28. British novelist throwing out precious metal gun (4, *abbr.*)
30. (*See 18 down*)

Comment: 11A is a fantastic clue!

Comment: @samm82 Thanks! Not thrilled to use "uniform" in two different clues like that but I really didn't want to remove it from either :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**COMPLETED GRID**

> [image: Grid]

**Today's Theme**

> THE PHILIPPINES...because many of the answers relate, and plus, it says so right across the top

**ACROSS**

> 1. PHILIP = PHIL + I_ P_
>  5. PINES = SPINE*
>  10. ANTIPODES = N + TIP in (described by) A (excellent) + ODES (I hope)
>  11. TANGO (predecessor of UNIFORM in NATO phonetic alphabet) = TAN + GO
>  12. NULL = NU + LL (lines)
>  13. [JOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jolo) = J-LO + O_
>  14. SIGN = (_N + GIS)<
>  17. PUT BACK = (-o + P)UTBACK (heading to (as in changing to) P_)
>  19. SKI JUMP (a snowy spring!) = SKIMP + JU(-dy)
>  20. [CEBUANO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cebuano_language) = CUBA* + _E + NO
>  22. [BASILAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilan) = BASIL(-i_c)A + _N
>  23. URNS = "EARNS"
>  24. LAUD = LAD + U_
>  25. CHAT = C (about, abbrev, for circa) + HAT (Panama)
>  29. ARMED = A + RED + M
>  31. NIGHTCLUB = THIN< (flippin' fine) + CLUB (suit) + G_
>  32. NARCO = RAN< + CO
>  33. MANILA = MA + ANIL

**DOWN**

> 2. HOTEL = HO (Chi Minh) + LET<
>  3. LAPP = "LAP"
>  4. PADLOCK = PAD(-d + L)OCK (turn topmost of dials to left (L))
>  5. PASTORS = PAST + OR + _S_
>  6. NUTS = STUN<
>  7. SAN MIGUEL = SANE + _L_ gets MIG (fighter) + U(niform)
>  8. MANNY PACQUIAO = MANNY (male carer, like nanny) + PA + (QUI(-t) (almost quit) + A) in CO (Colorado)
>  9. MOUNT PINATUBO = POINT OUT A NUMB*
>  15. DAVAO = AV(-oc)ADO*
>  16. TIPSY = (_Y + SPIT)<
>  18/30. TABON MAN = BATMAN NO*
>  21. ORLANDO = majOR LAND Operations
>  22. BLUE GUM = GLUE BUM per Spooner
>  26. HALAL = HAL + AL (from Arabic, commonly used for food in English-speaking countries)
>  27. ODER = OD(-d)ER
>  28. STEN = (-au)STEN

Comment: All correct, nice job! Still missing 11a, though? (From both the list and the grid)

Comment: Probably just a typo/mistake, but assuming that it isn't, 11A is rot13(GNA+TB: gnatb vf nsgre havsbez va gur angb cubargvp nycunorg) - somehow I managed to leave a comment specifically about this clue but not notice it wasn't present in this answer (:

Comment: @samm82 you mean "before" instead of "after".

Comment: Oh, man...that's what I get solving just before bed. I even looked twice to see if I forgot any entries :-( That was a great clue!